# Show activity below status bar without access to activity XML/code

Tags: android, android-layout, statusbar

I have used `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` in my `styles.xml` to remove the action bar in my  Android application. In all activities, I'm including a toolbar instead.

I am using a third party library (http://kokum.io) for user login in the app. I do not have control over the activity XML or code for the login screen that the library uses for authentication. The top of this activity is going behind the status bar.
[image: activity_behind_status_bar]

Is it possible to make the activity show up below the status bar without access to the activity code/XML?

Comment: Are you able to custom sth?

Comment: @tinysunlight i'm not able to customize the UI. But I need it to come below the status bar. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: if it's a third-party ,it usually provide some diy.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.
In `AndroidManifest.xml` we can specify themes specifically for each Activity.

```
<activity
    android:name="io.kokum.integration.LoginActivity"
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" />
```

This can override the app level theme specifically for this activity. 
In the specific case above, I was able to use a theme that provides an action bar to fix the issue.